# Android - How To Seperate Amount of Money Text with dot and comma

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I have `editText` and `textView` which I want to seperate and detect thousands automatically.

Here is user types; ($) 72500 
Here is what I want to see: 72.500,000

With this code, I can only seperate first section;

```
public String textFormatter(double formatThis){
    String str = String.format("%,d", (int) formatThis);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like that in your method :

```
NumberFormat numFormater = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(numFormater.format(new BigDecimal("72500")));//$72,500.00
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solved this just before. Can you also check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193443/edittext-cant-set-text-the-formatted-string