# EditText can't set text the formatted string

Tags: java, android

I want to format my EditText after every typing.
(e.g: User types 1234 and I correct as 1.234,00)

With this function, I format String correctly and I can see it on Toast message. But whenever I try to set text to edittext, it gives error after typing second number.

**This is my format function:**

```
 public String moneySeperator(double moneyAmount){
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", symbols);
    String prezzo = decimalFormat.format(moneyAmount);

    return prezzo;
}
```

**Here is my EditText listener:**

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

                String userInput = editText.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(Denemey.this, ""+moneySeperator(Double.parseDouble(userInput)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText.setText(""+moneySeperator(Double.parseDouble(userInput)));
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
```

**Here is the error:** *(It points editText.setText line)*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.incidijital.kdvtevkifati, PID: 7500
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15,00"
    at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
    at com.myproject.dd$1.afterTextChanged(Denemey.java:46)
```

**UPDATED:** I made my code really shorter. When I try a double like 1234.50
it works well on printing, but I think there is something wrong about afterTextChanged listener. My first 4 types (e.g: 1,234) works well, after I add more it crash because of Double.parseDouble casting, but there is no comma.
I removed formatter function.

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            java.text.NumberFormat formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMANY);


            if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
               double myDob = Double.parseDouble(""+editable);
                editText.setText(""+(formatter.format(myDob)));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
            }

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you checked if the EditText has the focus? if EditTexts has a focus then I would say before setting the text clear the focus and then try adding text on it. finally again requestFocus on it.

Comment: Its because of , symbol. You should debug your code and  format you string after parse into double

Comment: The problem is when after setting your formatted text you get callback in your text changelistener again, and here you are calling Double.parseDouble() , but this string in which you have inserted comma , is not parselable in double so throwing exception,

Comment: also try using NumberFormat as per the locale.ex. NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE); this will parse your input value with comma

Comment: Try to reset the formatted text on AfterTextChange because it contains formatted data , so first, remove the comma and then apply formatting

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all non numeric chars before parsing it as double. I am assuming here that your `#moneySeperator` working fine for format .

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String userInput = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        if(!userInput.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(Denemey.this, ""+moneySeperator(Double.parseDouble(userInput)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editText.setText(""+moneySeperator(Double.parseDouble(userInput)));
        }else{
            editText.setText("")
        }
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it types but this works reverse. I want it to be converted as 1.234,00 if I wrote 1234

Comment: You said in the question that formated string is correct . That means your formatting function working fine. How exactly edit text reversing the string here I can't see.

Comment: I fixed with editText.setSelection, but still adds more zeros. I updated and shortened my code, can you check the bottom of topic (updated part). Thanks for your replies.